# How can I explain predictions of an imblearn pipeline?

Tags: python, machine-learning, imblearn, smote

I have an **imblearn** (not sklearn) pipeline consisting of the following steps:

1. Column selector
2. Preprocessing pipeline (ColumnTransformer with OneHotEncoders and CountVectorizers on different columns)
3. imblearn's SMOTE
4. XGBClassifier

I have a tabular dataset and I'm trying to explain my predictions.
I managed to work out feature importance plots with some work, but can't get either
eli5 or lime to work.

Lime requires that I transform the data to the state of before the last transformation (because the transformers in the Pipeline like custom vectorizers create new columns).
In principle, I can slice my Pipeline like this: `pipeline[:-1].predict(instance)`. However, I get the following error: `{AttributeError}'SMOTE' object has no attribute 'predict'`.

I also tried an eli5 explainer, since it supposedly works with Sklearn Pipelines.
However, after running `eli5.sklearn.explain_prediction.explain_prediction_sklearn_not_supported(pipeline, instance_to_explain)` I get the message that the classifier is not supported.

Will appreciate any ideas on how to proceed with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imblearn's samplers are effectively no-op (ie. identity) transformers during prediction. Therefore, it should be safe to delete them after the pipeline has been fitted.

Try the following workflow:

1. Construct an Imblearn pipeline, and fit it.
2. Extract the steps of the fitted Imblearn pipeline to a new Scikit-Learn pipeline.
3. Delete the SMOTE step.
4. Explain your predictions using standard Scikit-Learn pipeline explanation tools.

Comment: Clarification: The order of steps #2 and #3 should be reversed (remove the SMOTE step from a fitted Imblearn pipeline, then carry all remaining steps over to a new Scikit-Learn pipeline). The reason is that a Scikit-Learn pipeline won't allow steps that don't implement the `(fit_)transform(X)` method.